# How reliable is the EFSET test?

Tags: proficiency-testing

I've recently taken the [EFSET](https://efset.org) and got a CEFR C2.

[My Certificate](https://efset.org/cert/jQ4KEE)

My question is, how reliable is that test? If not, is there a (hopefully not that expensive) way to get a accurate knowledge of my English skills, preferably in CEFR scale?

Specifically, I want to know:

1. How well do EFSET results map to other tests?
2. Which score am I likely to get in other tests, say IELTS?